# Compiling Error using CGAL and GMP

Tags: hyperlink, gmp, cgal

maybe someone can help me get this working. For creating meshes out from pointclouds I installed CGAL 4.7 on Win7 x64 and after using Cmake I successfully compiled it using VS2012.
In a test project i want to build an example found on CGAL docs http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction_2reconstruction_surface_mesh_8cpp-example.html
In my project i linked/included CGAL and boost and the gmp library (that one that comes with the CGAL install). But if compiling this little test still i get this error message:

```html
1>  ConsoleApplication1.cpp
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp___gmpq_add" in Funktion ""class CGAL::Gmpq __cdecl CGAL::operator+(class CGAL::Gmpq const &,class CGAL::Gmpq const &)" (??HCGAL@@YA?AVGmpq@0@AEBV10@0@Z)".
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp___gmpq_clear" in Funktion ""public: __cdecl CGAL::Gmpq_rep::~Gmpq_rep(void)" (??1Gmpq_rep@CGAL@@QEAA@XZ)".
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp___gmpq_cmp" in Funktion ""public: bool __cdecl CGAL::Gmpq::operator<(class CGAL::Gmpq const &)const " (??MGmpq@CGAL@@QEBA_NAEBV01@@Z)".
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp___gmpq_init" in Funktion ""public: __cdecl CGAL::Gmpq_rep::Gmpq_rep(void)" (??0Gmpq_rep@CGAL@@QEAA@XZ)".
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp___gmpq_mul" in Funktion ""class CGAL::Gmpq __cdecl CGAL::operator*(class CGAL::Gmpq const &,class CGAL::Gmpq const &)" (??DCGAL@@YA?AVGmpq@0@AEBV10@0@Z)".
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp___gmpq_set_d" in Funktion ""public: __cdecl CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(double)" (??0Gmpq@CGAL@@QEAA@N@Z)".
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp___gmpq_sub" in Funktion ""class CGAL::Gmpq __cdecl CGAL::operator-(class CGAL::Gmpq const &,class CGAL::Gmpq const &)" (??GCGAL@@YA?AVGmpq@0@AEBV10@0@Z)".
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp___gmpn_add_n" in Funktion "__gmpn_add".
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp___gmpn_mul" in Funktion ""struct CGAL::Mpzf __cdecl CGAL::operator*(struct CGAL::Mpzf const &,struct CGAL::Mpzf const &)" (??DCGAL@@YA?AUMpzf@0@AEBU10@0@Z)".
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp___gmpn_sqr" in Funktion ""struct CGAL::Mpzf __cdecl CGAL::Mpzf_square(struct CGAL::Mpzf const &)" (?Mpzf_square@CGAL@@YA?AUMpzf@1@AEBU21@@Z)".
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp___gmpn_sub_n" in Funktion "__gmpn_sub".
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp___gmpn_copyi" in Funktion ""public: __cdecl CGAL::Mpzf::Mpzf(struct CGAL::Mpzf const &)" (??0Mpzf@CGAL@@QEAA@AEBU01@@Z)".
1>C:\Users\cap\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 12 nicht aufgelöste Externe
```

So i suspect there are still some dependencys missing, but which ones?
Thanks in advance

forgot the command lines:
c/c++

```html
/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\Users\cap\Documents\cpp_libraries\CGAL-4.7\auxiliary\gmp\include" /I"C:\Users\cap\Documents\cpp_libraries\CGAL-4.7\build\include" /I"C:\Users\cap\Documents\cpp_libraries\boost_1_54_0" /I"C:\Users\cap\Documents\cpp_libraries\CGAL-4.7\include" /Zi /Gm /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc110.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pch"
```

linker:

```html
/OUT:"C:\Users\cap\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\cap\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Users\cap\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\cap\Documents\cpp_libraries\CGAL-4.7\auxiliary\gmp\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\cap\Documents\cpp_libraries\boost_1_54_0\lib64-msvc-11.0" /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\cap\Documents\cpp_libraries\CGAL-4.7\build\lib" /TLBID:1
```

Comment: I can't see the command that caused these error messages, so I can only guess. You need to link with GMP.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2015 (and I assume in Visual Studio 2012) you need to specify the actual lib files **in addition** to the directories where to look for those files (as explained here: [When to use the Visual Studio Additional dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066405/when-to-use-the-visual-studio-additional-dependencies)).

Looking at your linker command, I see that you have specified the directory to the GMP/MPFR libs (`/LIBPATH:"C:\Users\cap\Documents\cpp_libraries\CGAL-4.7\auxiliary\gmp\lib`), but you also need to specify the actual lib files by adding them to the `/DYNAMICBASE` list:

```
/DYNAMICBASE "libgmp-10.lib" "libmpfr-4.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" ...
```